# Split, replace and concatenate a string in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, string, xslt, soap, xslt-2.0

I have an XSLT which will be transformed from a SOAP Response xml to a Java object.

In the soap response there is node called `urn:Statues` which has comma(,) separated string.

I want to split the value of `urn:Statues` node and replace some of the value and again concatenate those into a string with comma(,) separated.

**Soap Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:urn="urn:HPD_Incident_Query_WS">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse>
            <urn:ErrorCode>0</urn:ErrorCode>
            <urn:Incidents_Number>INC80167842,INC77752907,INC20954581,INC20954533</urn:Incidents_Number>
            <urn:Statuses>CLOSED,CANCELLED,En Curso,Cerrado</urn:Statuses>
        </urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My XSLT :**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:HPD_Incident_Query_WS">
    <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes' />

    <xsl:template match="urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse" name="split">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(./urn:Statuses,',')">
            <xsl:if test="(normalize-space(.) eq 'Cerrado')">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space(.), 'Cerrado', 'CLOSED')"/>  
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(normalize-space(.) eq 'CANCELLED')">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space(.), 'CANCELLED', 'CLOSED')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(normalize-space(.) eq 'En Curso')">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space(.), 'En Curso', 'OPENACTIVE')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(normalize-space(.) eq 'Pendiente')">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space(.), 'Pendiente', 'CLOSED.PENDING')"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <getTicketInfoResponse>
            <responseCode>
                <xsl:value-of select='/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ResponseCode' />
            </responseCode>
            <responseMessage>
                <xsl:value-of select='/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ResponseMsg' />
            </responseMessage>
            <errorCode>
                <xsl:value-of select='/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ErrorCode' />
            </errorCode>
            <errorMsg>
                <xsl:value-of select='/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ErrorMsg' />
            </errorMsg>
            <ticketDetails>
                <troubleTicketState>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body"/>
                </troubleTicketState>
                <troubleTicketId>
                    <xsl:value-of select='/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:Incidents_Number' />
                </troubleTicketId>
            </ticketDetails>
        </getTicketInfoResponse>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue here is, when the value is set to `urn:Statuses` the values are not separated by comma(,).

**Current Result after transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getTicketInfoResponse xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:urn="urn:HPD_Incident_Query_WS">
   <responseCode/>
   <responseMessage/>
   <errorCode>0</errorCode>
   <errorMsg/>
   <ticketDetails>
      <troubleTicketState> CLOSEDCLOSEDOPENACTIVECLOSED</troubleTicketState>
      <troubleTicketId>INC80167842,INC77752907,INC20954581,INC20954533</troubleTicketId>
   </ticketDetails>
</getTicketInfoResponse>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getTicketInfoResponse xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:urn="urn:HPD_Incident_Query_WS">
   <responseCode/>
   <responseMessage/>
   <errorCode>0</errorCode>
   <errorMsg/>
   <ticketDetails>
      <troubleTicketState>CLOSED,CLOSED,OPENACTIVE,CLOSED</troubleTicketState>
      <troubleTicketId>INC80167842,INC77752907,INC20954581,INC20954533</troubleTicketId>
   </ticketDetails>
</getTicketInfoResponse>
```

Can someone tell how to separate the string by comma(,) in the resulting tag `<troubleTicketState>`.

Is there any better way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
xmlns:urn='urn:HPD_Incident_Query_WS'>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope">
    <getTicketInfoResponse>
        <responseCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ResponseCode" />
        </responseCode>
        <responseMessage>
            <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ResponseMsg" />
        </responseMessage>
        <errorCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ErrorCode" />
        </errorCode>
        <errorMsg>
            <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:ErrorMsg" />
        </errorMsg>
        <ticketDetails>
            <troubleTicketState>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:Statuses" />
            </troubleTicketState>
            <troubleTicketId>
                <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Body/urn:Incident_Query_ServiceResponse/urn:Incidents_Number" />
            </troubleTicketId>
        </ticketDetails>
    </getTicketInfoResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="urn:Statuses">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(replace(replace(., 'Cerrado', 'CLOSED'), 'CANCELLED', 'CLOSED'), 'En Curso', 'OPENACTIVE'), 'Pendiente', 'CLOSED.PENDING')"/> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @amit4497 Please note that this assumes the replaced values do not appear as substrings in other values.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the last part.

Comment: I meant if you replace 'Cerrado' with 'CLOSED' it will also change 'Cerrados' to 'CLOSEDs' etc. Probably not applicable to your case, but worth mentioning just in case.